# Open source GIS tool for mapping health data

Tags: open-source-gis, visualisation, analysis

Im looking for an open source desktop gis tool that can be used for visualization and exploratory analysis.

I want it to be interactive and perhaps display two or more maps at the same time to allow for comparative analysis.

I know CommonGIS allows for this, but are there any others?

thanks!

Comment: Hi @hhart - what kind of data sources do you have?

Comment: @celenius I don't know what type of data I will be working with yet. I'm familiar with .shp, and .tab files. I expect to be working with census data and time series health data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to give the [Exploratory Spatio-Temporal Analysis Toolkit](http://www.geovista.psu.edu/ESTAT/index.html) a spin and see how it works for your data.

[image]

> Developed by the GeoVISTA Center in close cooperation with users at
>   the National Cancer Institute, the ESTAT toolkit provides
>   user-friendly, open-source software designed to support exploratory
>   geographic visualization.
>
> While developed initially to support cancer research, ESTAT is
>   designed to handle any kind of spatial data with attributes. If you
>   have an ESRI ArcGIS shapefile, you can follow our tutorial on the in
>   practice page to quickly convert your data into something ESTAT can
>   use.

The site also has [tutorials](http://www.geovista.psu.edu/ESTAT/estat_practice.html) with [sample data](http://www.geovista.psu.edu/ESTAT/files/ESTAT_Tutorial.doc) and another one for working with [your own data](http://www.geovista.psu.edu/ESTAT/files/ESTAT%20Data%20Tutorial.doc).